# Misalignment with framed package and column

Tags: beamer, framed, columns

I'm trying to use the shaded environment as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{1,0.8,0.3}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}[t, totalwidth=\linewidth]
\begin{column}{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{shaded}
Foo
\end{shaded}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.5\linewidth}
Foo
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I get the following output (although, oddly, there is no Overfull hbox error): 
[image: misalignment]

Without the shaded environment around the first "foo", I get

[image]

Do I need to give up on the shaded environment, or I am doing something else wrong?

Comment: The answer will depend on what exactly are you trying to achieve. Can you please describe in detail your intent?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina In the left column, I have a list of (important) equations, along with some descriptive text, in the itemize environment. On the right, I have some (not so important) text. Does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `minipage`s instead of the `columns` environment solves the problem. I'd suggest you to use [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) or [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox)instead of `framed`; the former packages are more versatile and easily customizable:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{framed}

\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{1,0.8,0.3}

% for mdframed
\newmdenv[
  hidealllines=true,
  backgroundcolor=shadecolor,
  userdefinedwidth=.6\linewidth
  ]{mybox}

% for tcolorbox
\newtcolorbox{mytbox}[1][]{
  colback=shadecolor,
  colframe=shadecolor,
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  #1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
With \texttt{framed} package:
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{shaded}
Foo
\end{shaded}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
Foo
\end{minipage}\vfill

With \texttt{mdframed} package:
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{mybox}[userdefinedwidth=.95\linewidth]
Foo
\end{mybox}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
Foo
\end{minipage}\vfill

With \texttt{tcolorbox} package:
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{mytbox}[width=.95\linewidth]
Foo
\end{mytbox}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
Foo
\end{minipage}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]